# HTML5 nav tag content

Tags: html

There seems to be conflicting examples in documents relating to the `<nav>` tag in html5. Most examples I've seen use this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

But I'm wondering if that's only because people are used to using divs. There are examples that I've seen that simply do this

```
<nav>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
</nav>
```

The second way seems cleaner and more semantic to me. Is there an "official" correct version? Is there a good reason to still use a `<ul>` inside the nav tag rather than just use anchor elements directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both examples are semantic.

In the first example, the list of anchors is explicitly an unordered list. In the second example, the list of links is just a collection of anchor elements.

If you simply want a one-dimensional collection of links, I recommend sticking with

```
<nav>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
  <a href='#'>Link</a>
</nav>
```

however, using `ul` elements allows for explicit hierarchical menus (such as drop-downs or tree-lists):

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The first version is better for screen readers (can't remember the source right now).

Comment: @Teetrinker, the first one is a list, the second is a tree. Neither is *better* for screen readers because they convey completely different meanings. If you intend to convey a tree, then the first would be unacceptable.

Comment: The argument was that a screen reader reads: "navigation / a list / first item / link to A / second item / link to B.." versus "navigation / link to A / link to B..."
I totally get your point with the tree.

Answer (score 1):

The only real difference might be how search engines might look at the links.  When in an unordered list Google might for example understand that all the items in that list are related.  In the second example Google might just as well assume none of the links are related.  Google can use that information for indexing and display your information more accurately.

They may display the same, but really a lot of markup is about how information should be presented if there was no style attached to the page at all or if a bot is searching your website for relevant information.

Comment: Google or anywhere mention the item that actually has a meaning and interpreted it as you say?

Comment: @djlukas777 Google really doesn't disclose much of what googlebot does for obvious reasons, but it's clear googlebot cares about semantic markup.  Understanding what semantic markup is really the key to understanding googlebot.  Lists go in list item tags, Google then understands that it is looking at a list.  If it's a paragraph tag, then Google knows it's a paragraph.  Use the right tags in the right places and googlebot will like you.  Use paragraph tags for something other than paragraphs, then googlebot will not like you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either.

A list only tends to be used as a list of links is generally just that, a list. But, it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference between them. However like Caimen said, search engines use the page markup to group data to better web search results. I'd advise you use the first if the links are quite similar on topic (eg for a blog) and the second if the links aren't so similar (for navigating results from a website search).